# What is the most performant way to do both a DB query and a DB update in a single API call in Next.js with Prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, promise, prisma

I have a API route that returns a blogpost by ID.

I also want to update the viewcount on this blogpost in the same API call that fetches the post.

What is the fastest way to do this? I want to show the blogpost as fast as possible, while also incrementing its counter.

I use Next.js and Prisma ORM with PostgreSQL from supabase.

I was thinking of using Promise.All like this:

```
export default async function handle(req, res) {
   const { id } = req.query;

   const blogpost = prisma.post.findUnique({
     where: {
       id: id
     });

   const incrementPost = prisma.post.update({
     where: {
      id: id
     },
     data: {
       views: { increment: 1 }
     });
   
  Promise.all([blogpost, incrementPost])
  .then((values) => {
     res.status(200).json({values[0]})
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    res.status(500)
  });
}
```

Is this a good way to solve this?

User model could be like this:

```
model User {
 id String @id @default(cuid())
 title String
 body String
 views Int @default(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update something in Prisma, it will return the updated item as part of the update operation. From your code, `incrementPost` and `blogpost` will both refer to the same post. So you can just return `incrementPost` from your API.

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-a-single-record

```js
export default async function handle(req, res) {
    const {
        id
    } = req.query;

    prisma.post.update({
            where: {
                id: id
            },
            data: {
                views: {
                    increment: 1
                }
            })
        .then((updatedpost) => {
            res.status(200).json(updatedpost)
        });
        .catch(() => res.status(500));
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I should have thought about that.

My example was simplified, my real application uses findFirst with multiple where parameters.

If I were to use update as the sole prisma action I would have to use updateMany:
let post = await prisma.post.updateMany({
 where: {
  id: id,
  deletedAt: null,
  published: { not: null },
  creatorId: creatorId
}

This returns  { count: 1 }.
I'm not sure how to get the edited post from that.

I still also wonder about the concept of two actions in a single api call though. If anyone got insights for that I'd appreciate that aswell :)

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are trying to accomplish with Prisma. Unless you have the unique ID (or other unique attribute) of the post, you won't be able to update-and-return the item. If you are 100% confident that your `where` clause will always return exactly one post (and never more than one), perhaps you can consider adding a `@@unique` attribute to the Post model to allow you to use `findUnique` on that combination of attributes? https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unique-1

Comment: Looks like Prisma 4.5.0 might be shipping with a preview feature to help solve this problem: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-on-non-unique-fields-with-userwhereuniqueinput

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shea for providing the solution that works for me!

I made a @@unique([creatorId, slug]) in my model, and used the new [UserWhereUniqueInput](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-on-non-unique-fields-with-userwhereuniqueinput) in Prisma 4.5.0 to run an update on my Post model.

I only have username and slug to identify the post from my frontend.

```
let post = await prisma.post.update({
      where: {
        creatorId_slug: {
          creatorId: user.id,
          slug: slug,
        },
        deletedAt: null,
        published: {
          not: null
        }
      },
      data: {
        views: {
          increment: 1
        }
      },
      include: {
         image: true
      }
}
```

This returns the post and increments the "views" in one go, and solves my problem!

Simplified Model from my real app:

```
model Post {
  id String @id @default(cuid())

  published DateTime?
  creatorId String

  userId Int
  user   UserInfo @relation("posts", fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  title  String
  body   String
  slug   String

  @@unique([creatorId,slug])
}
```